# Is it possible to override the Getter/Setter functions in a powershell 5 class?

Tags: powershell

I recently started creating classes with powershell 5. While I was following this awesome guide https://xainey.github.io/2016/powershell-classes-and-concepts/#methods

I was wondering if it is possible to override the `get_x` and `set_x` methods.

Example:

```
Class Foobar2 {
    [string]$Prop1    
}

$foo = [Foobar2]::new()
$foo | gm



Name        MemberType Definition                    
----        ---------- ----------                    
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method     type GetType()                
ToString    Method     string ToString()             
Prop1       Property   string Prop1 {get;set;}
```

I would like to do it because I think it would be easier for other to access the properties than using my custom `Get` and `Set` methods:

```
Class Foobar {
    hidden [string]$Prop1

    [string] GetProp1() {
        return $this.Prop1
    }

    [void] SetProp1([String]$Prop1) {
        $this.Prop1 = $Prop1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately the new Classes feature does not have facilities for getter/setter properties like you know them from C#.

You can however add a `ScriptProperty` member to an existing instance, which will exhibit similar behavior as a Property in C#:

```
Class FooBar
{
    hidden [string]$_prop1
}

$FooBarInstance = [FooBar]::new()
$FooBarInstance |Add-Member -Name Prop1 -MemberType ScriptProperty -Value {
    # This is the getter
    return $this._prop1
} -SecondValue {
    param($value)
    # This is the setter
    $this._prop1 = $value
}
```

Now you can access `$_prop1` through the `Prop1` property on the object:

```
$FooBarInstance.Prop1
$FooBarInstance.Prop1 = "New Prop1 value"
```

Comment: Great. This even seems to work, if i add the new variable within the class constructor. Unfortunately I can't override the existing property like [Gist Example](https://gist.github.com/OCram85/03ce8c0f881477c835e3fdfc279dfed7)

Comment: @OCram85 No, you'll have to use a hidden backing field with another name like in my example

Answer (score 11):

Just to expand on Mathias's answer...

You can include the "add-member" part to a constructor for the class so that it will automagically be added simply by instantiating the class.

Using Mathias's answer as an example:

```
Class FooBar
{
    hidden [string]$_prop1

    FooBar(){
        $this | Add-Member -Name Prop1 -MemberType ScriptProperty -Value {
            # This is the getter
            return $this._prop1
        } -SecondValue {
            param($value)
            # This is the setter
            If ($value -eq 'foo'){$value = 'bar'}
            $this._prop1 = $value
        }
    }
}
```

Creating a class method with the same name as the class will override the "constructor" for the class.  The section of code in that method will run every time you create a new "foobar" object.  Here we are incorporating the Add-Member cmdlet to add the scriptproperty for us just from creating the object.

```
$FooBarInstance = [FooBar]::new()

$FooBarInstance.Prop1 = 'Egon Spenglar'
Write-host $FooBarInstance.Prop1 -ForegroundColor Green
```

If you pass anything into it (as in assignment in this case), it will change the _Prop1 property to equal whatever you pass into it.  (in this case "Egon Spenglar").  _Prop1 is a "Hidden" property so that you normally wont see it on the object, we're just using it to store and retrieve information with this added script property.

Then, if you call the Prop1 property without any arguments, it will just return the value in _Prop1.

```
$FooBarInstance.Prop1 = 'foo'
Write-host $FooBarInstance.Prop1 -ForegroundColor Green
```

And as an example as to why you might want to do something like this, there is a little logic added to the "Add-Member" cmdlet that checks to see if you are passing in the string "foo", and if so, it will store "bar" instead.

This second example will return "bar".

Comment: When I use this now, I usually create a method named _AddPropName(), then add that to any constructors.  Makes it much tidier when you want to make a bunch of constructors for a class.

Answer (score 8):

Actually I may suggest another approach to solve this limitation of PowerShell's Classes, because of the high cost of adding the script properties in this way (**Using the instance's constructor & Add-Member command**) since this means that every time create an instance of this class :-(

Think of a scenario of creating hundreds (or may be thousands objects of this class), For example:

```
$myList = 1..10|% { $obj = [FooBar]::new();  $obj.Prop1 = "$_"; $obj; }
```

The code above will creates a 10 objects of that class and save in the variable.

by adding a display message to the constrictor using  (Write-Host) to Mathias's answer as follow:

```
Class myFooBar
{
    hidden [string]$_prop1

    myFooBar(){
        #Display message for this solution.
        Write-Host "Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)" -ForegroundColor  Cyan;
        $this | Add-Member -Name Prop1 -MemberType ScriptProperty -Value {
            # This is the getter
            return $this._prop1
        } -SecondValue {
            param($value)
            # This is the setter
            $this._prop1 = $value
        }
    }


}
```

Now trying the same test above of creating 10 objects:

```
$myList = 1..10|% { $obj = [myFooBar]::new();  $obj.Prop1 = "$_"; $obj; }
```

This would generates the following output:

```
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
```

This behavior would be worse if your class having a lot of properties and you are planning to create a hundreds instances of this class during the Runtime.

**A BETTER SOLUTION:**

Might be achieved by utilizing the (static constructor) and (Update-TypeData) that would creates the properties ONLY ONCE even if you run the test again no more properties will be added to all the instances as they have been added to type data once (And that will affects all the new instances directly).

To make it clearer I will modify the class code and add another property called prop2 but using the static modification for myFooBar type instead of the instance creator (& using **Update-TypeData** command instead of **Add-Member**) as follow:

```
Class myFooBar
{
    hidden [string]$_prop1
    hidden [string]$_prop2

    myFooBar(){
        Write-Host "Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)" -ForegroundColor  Cyan;
        $this | Add-Member -Name Prop1 -MemberType ScriptProperty -Value {
            # This is the getter
            return $this._prop1
        } -SecondValue {
            param($value)
            # This is the setter
            $this._prop1 = $value
        }
    }

    static  myFooBar(){
        Write-Host "Prop2 Setup (Only Once)" -ForegroundColor  Yellow;
        "myFooBar" | Update-TypeData -MemberName Prop2 -MemberType ScriptProperty -Value {
            # This is the getter
            return $this._prop2;
        } -SecondValue {
            param($value)
            # This is the setter
            $this._prop2 = $value;
        } -Force
    }
}
```

Running our creation test twice as follow :

```
write-host "Test (first call):-----------------" -ForegroundColor Green;
$myList1 = 1..10|% { $obj = [myFooBar]::new();  $obj.Prop1 = "$_"; $obj.Prop2 = "$_"; $obj; };

write-host "Test (Second call):-----------------" -ForegroundColor Green;
$myList2 = 1..10|% { $obj = [myFooBar]::new();  $obj.Prop1 = "$_"; $obj.Prop2 = "$_"; $obj; };
```

The output as follow :

```
Test (first call):-----------------
Prop2 Setup (Only Once) # <------------------ (Prop2)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Test (Second call):-----------------
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
Prop1 Setup (Called Many Times)
```

Note that the Prop2 setup code executed once no matter how many objects you are creating or how many times you are repeating the calls no more properties will be created as they have been added to the type it self not the instances.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the helpful answers in this post, I have created a [`Use-ClassAccessors`](https://github.com/iRon7/Use-ClassAccessors) cmdlet to update accessors according to the `get_`/`set_` suggestion in issue [Properties with accessor and mutator methods](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2219) mainly because the class syntax is *downwards* compatible with Windows PowerShell:

##### `getter` syntax

```
[<type>] get_<property name>() {
  return <value>
}
```

##### `setter` syntax

```
set_<property name>(<value>) {
  <code>
}
```

#### General usage

```
Install-Script Use-ClassAccessors
```

Create a script (e.g. `ExampleClass.ps1`) with the following contents:

```
Class ExampleClass {
    hidden $_Value
    hidden [Object] get_Value() {
      return $this._Value
    }
    hidden set_Value($Value) {
      $this._Value = $Value
    }
    hidden [Type]get_Type() {
      if ($Null -eq $this.Value) { return $Null }
      else { return $this._Value.GetType() }
    }
    hidden static ExampleClass() { Use-ClassAccessors }
}

$Example = [ExampleClass]::new()

Write-Host '# $Example.Value = 42'
$Example.Value = 42

Write-Host '# $Example.Value'
$Example.Value

Write-Host '# $Example.Type'
$Example.Type

Write-Host "# $Example.Type = 'Something'"
$Example.Type = 'Something'
```

Invoke the script (`ExampleClass.ps1`).
Result:

```
# $Example.Value = 42
# $Example.Value
42
# $Example.Type

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType

# ExampleClass.Type = 'Something'
InvalidOperation: C:\Users\Gebruiker\My Drive\Scripts\PowerShell\Temp\ExampleClass.ps1:29
Line |
  29 |  $Example.Type = 'Something'
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | 'Type' is a ReadOnly property.
```

See also: [`#21079` Implement Class Accessors](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/21079)