# Why doesn't overloading the get_/set_ functions work as expected?

Tags: class, powershell-5.0

So apparently, custom getter and setter methods [are not supported with Powershell Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977472/is-it-possible-to-override-the-getter-setter-functions-in-a-powershell-5-class).

When examining a Powershell object instance built from a Powershell v5 class, we see that defining `[type]Property` for the class would create hidden `[type]get_Property()` and `[void]set_Property([type])` methods in the object instance:

```
class myClass {
    [int]$Property
}

[myClass]::new() | Get-Member -Force | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*Property" }
```

---

```
   TypeName: myClass

Name         MemberType Definition             
----         ---------- ----------             
get_Property Method     int get_Property()     
set_Property Method     void set_Property(int )
Property     Property   int Property {get;set;}
```

If the getter/setter methods would have been crucial for accessing the properties using the `=` operator like the `.Equals([object])` method is called by the `-eq` and `-ne` operators, we should be able to overload the default getter/setter methods and see it *simply work*:

```
class myClass {
    [int]$Property

    hidden [void]set_Property([int]$Property) {
        $this.Property=$Property * 10
    }

    [boolean]Equals([object]$Element) {
        Return $true
    }
}
```

Yet, the `=` operator is definitely not calling `$leftObject.set_Property($right)`:

```
$myObject = [myClass]::new()
$myObject.Property = 3
$myObject.Property
```

---

```
3
```

At the same time, we see that `-eq` is indeed calling `([myClass]$left).Equals($right)`:

```
$myObject -eq "anything"
```

---

```
True
```

So, looking at the mechanics of Powershell Classes implementation, ***why*** have the properties' getters/setters built as hidden methods if they are not used by the `=` operator anyway? Is there any technical reason the getter/setter methods are implicitly created or is it just some convenience or convention without any kind of operator binding?

Comment: Really looking for documentation on overloading get_ & set_ methods when declaring classes.  Hope someone comes along and answers this!

Comment: I'm interested in understanding why this behaves this way as well. Even force-adding a `ScriptMethod` to an instantiated object with the same signature as the hidden getter or setter "succeeds", but the class method still gets called when you invoke the property it's bound to. Even understanding the decision behind ignoring the developer's code that explicitly overloads the getter or setter for a property is perplexing.