# Get Class Source

Tags: powershell, class, abstract-syntax-tree

A few months ago I wrote a small [`Use-ClassAccessors`](https://github.com/iRon7/Use-ClassAccessors) script to easier define class accessors (getters and setters).
This works pretty well except for a minor constraint: The `Use-ClassAccessors` script needs to be invoked from the script file were the concerned class resides so that it can load the related [AST](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/learn-how-it-pros-can-use-the-powershell-ast/) information of the class. The unfortunate side effect is that the accessors are not always reloaded in the module¹ were I am working on with VSCode. The workaround is to a **Kill Terminal** and load a new one.

1. The module `psd1` also invokes the script that contains the class and the `Use-ClassAccessors` function with `ScriptsToProcess` but this apparently doesn't reload when changes are made to the class itself.

I suspect that I might be able to resolve this issue if I would be able to run the `Use-ClassAccessors` function from a static constructor as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72333019/1701026).

The point is that I have no clue how I might get to the (AST) source code of the class it**self**.

In other words:
Is there a way to retrieve the Class' own ScriptBlock from within the concerned class similar as I could do in a function:

```
function GetMyCode {
    Write-Host 'My Source Code:'
    $MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need access to the AST for this at all - you can extract all the requisite information via reflection :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, good point, I need to give this some thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be an XY problem: you don't actually need access to the source code (or resulting AST) to discover the information required, you can obtain it from the resulting type at runtime:

```
$targetType = $ClassName -as [Type]

if ($targetType.Assembly.GetName().Name -notmatch 'PowerShell Class Assembly') {
  # not a powershell class 
  return
}

$accessorMethods = $targetType.GetMethods() |? Name -Like "?et_${PropertyName}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did some quick tests and it looks indeed that all required information is available from the "*static constructor*" (I need some more time to actually rewrite my function). @mklement0, this answer is a good (counter) example for the: [What's wrong with my answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419923/1701026) meta issue.

Comment: @iRon Happy to help! FWIW "static constructor" has a specific meaning in many .NET-languages (in C# it usually describes an explicit static initializer) - `$targetType` is just an instance of type `[type]` :)